# How to find a parametrization of the set $\left\{(x,y,z): e^x+e^{-x}=z-\sqrt3y, 0<y<x<1\right\}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces

I have to find surface area of set $M=\left\{(x,y,z): e^x+e^{-x}=z-\sqrt3y, 0<y<x<1\right\}$ and my problem is to parametrize it, may you help me?

Comment: The given equation can be rearranged as $z = f(x,y)$ so you can just use $x$ and $y$ as parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pick as a parametrization

\begin{equation}
\phi(x,y) : (0,1)\text{ x }(0,1)\to\mathbb R^3 : (x,y)\mapsto (x,y,e^x+e^{-x}+\sqrt3y)
\end{equation}

You just use the domain given in the definition and set z as in the equation you have above. :)

Comment: So it was so simple... Thank you.